# baseconfig files?

Tags: time-capsule

I have a couple of files on my desktop:

> myName Time Capsule.baseconfig
>
> default.baseconfig

Both go back to August 12, 2011.

What is a "baseconfig" file?

Can I delete them without messing up Time Capsule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can delete them.

They are copies of old Airport Utility configuration files for your Time Capsule. Time Capsule does not refer to these files unless you specifically decide to reload an old config file into your Time Capsule. in most cases you would be better off configuring through Airport Utility and not bothering with keeping copies of those configurations unless you have a particular reason.

One possible reason for keeping config files could be a time-saving measure for frequently moving a Time Capsule from one network to another and back again so that you keep a copy of each configuration and reload that configuration when it has moved to new location. In most cases you would not have a particular need to keep config files.